# What is the required Microsoft SQL Server configuration to connect from Node.js on a Mac?

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2008

I have tried a lot of variations of the following and get:

```
 CONNECT ERROR: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 192.168.1.5:53394 in 15000ms
```

with:

```
 var sql     = require('mssql');
 var SERVER = process.argv[2] || '192.168.1.5';
 var DATABASE = process.argv[3] || 'PRODUCTION';
 var connection = new sql.Connection({
     server: SERVER,
     //database: DATABASE,
     userName:     '...',
     password: '...',
     connectionTimeout: 15000,
     driver: 'tedious',
     options: {
        //encrypt: true,
        port: 53394,
        database: DATABASE,
        instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'
     }
 });

  connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) { console.log('CONNECT ERROR: '+err); }
      else { console.log('CONNECTED!'); }
  });
```

Comment: can you reach the sql server using telnet? >> telnet 192.168.1.5 53394

Comment: No, it times out...   If I type the incorrect instanceName (test in the following example), I get: `CONNECT ERROR: ConnectionError: Port for test not found in ServerName;...;InstanceName;SQLEXPRESS;IsClustered;No;Version;10.50.4000.0;tcp;53394;np;\\...\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query;;`